# Julia DataFrames Unique Rows

Tags: dataframe, julia, unique, rows

In DF, I have two columns (let’s call them A and B) with A having repeats, both are categorical variables. I am trying to show only the unique A rows with their corresponding B values, how can I do that?

I was able to do it when B is a continuous var by using this:

```
by(ptable, [:A], df -> mean(df[:B]))
```

Comment: Hey Kevin, welcome to StackOverflow! It's generally a good idea to show what you have tried and to provide a minimal example which everyone can copy&paste.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```html
df[!nonunique(df[:,[:A]]), [:A, :B]]
```

Comment: You can write it shorter as `unique(df, :A)` and this is the same as your answer. However, this does not produce what you have written you wanted, as you will have only one value of `:B` column per unique value of `:A` column and there might be different values of `:B` for the same value of `:A` in your `DataFrame`. My solution lists all values of `:B` that correspond to a single value of `:A`. So what you choose depends what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the desired result like this:

```
by(df, :A, x -> [x.B])
```

now your `DataFrame` will have two columns `:A` and `:x1`, and column `:x1` will hold all values of column `:B` corresponding to unique values of `:A` (so column `:x1` will be a vector of vectors).

EDIT: as of DataFrames.jl 0.22 use the following syntax:

```
combine(groupby(df, :A), :B => Ref => :B)
```

Comment: when i ran the line you wrote i got this error: SubDataFrame has no field B.. what do you think? Thanks

Comment: You are probably using Julia 0.6 not Julia 0.7 or 1.0. If this is so use `x[:B]` it is equivalent. The dot notation was introduced in Julia 0.7.

Comment: Just to be clear the whole line in Julia 0.6 should be `by(df, :A, x -> [x[:B]])`.

Comment: For reference, `by` has been deprecated in favor of `combine(groupby(...), ...)`. But better use `unique(df, :A)`.

Comment: Actually it changed completely (I believe in a better way). I have edited the answer.